# I have a wxwidgets that I want to add some cool effects. Using GDI would be impossibly hard. Could I use flash or something else?

Tags: c++, flash, winapi, animation, wxwidgets

I have an application that I want add some cool animations to show state changes. However, wxwidgets would be difficult because I'd have to program these animations in straight gdi. What's the best way to add these effect windows? Should I open a flash window and run a flash sequence or is maybe some other technology? Does .net have something I could code into a dll and run from my wxwidgets binary? I need something that is super easy to draw and set up the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepare animation as a bunch of images (wxImage loaded from PNG, GIF, JPG or whatever files), and then use a timer and paint them on a control. Maybe it sounds like too much, you I believe you could do it in 50-70 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the best approach would be to achieve "cool effects", but in most cases you would want a double-buffered drawing surface.  That's what I've used in similar-sounding situations.

In wxWidgets, you would want [wxBufferedDC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.7/wx_wxbuffereddc.html#wxbuffereddc).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just could make a single widget that has a custom paint-event that hand-draws the various widgets inside it?  Then you could draw them at the appropriate locations/sizes without having to involve wxwidgets at all, it would just be a bunch of line-draw/rectangle-draw/text-draw commands to update the display for each frame of animation.